# Aggregate Mongodb collection using a cursor

Tags: mongodb

I've got two Mongodb collections like rollnumber and studentdetails:

```
rollnumber:

{
"roll" : 34
"displayFlag" : "H"
}


studentdetails:
{
_id : {
"roll" : 34
"examdate" : "2020-08-24"},
measures : [
 "subject" : " Maths"
 "marks" : 99

_id : {
"roll" : 34
"examdate" : "2020-08-25"},
measures : [
 "subject" : " Maths"
 "marks" : 100


}]
```

The output desired is :

```
roll subject total_marks
34    Maths    199
```

There are lots of enteries in rollnumber and studentdetails, i only want to aggregate total marks obtained by someone who's rollnumber is available in the "rollnumber" collection. Here's my approach:

```
db.rollnumber.find({"displayFlag":"H"}).forEach(function(myDoc){

db.studentdetails.aggregate({[
{ $unwind: "$_id"},
{ $unwind: "$measures"},
{ $match: { roll: myDoc.roll } },
{ $group: {_id : {subject:"$measures.subject",roll:"$roll"}, total_marks: { $sum: "$measures.marks"} } }
});
```

The query is not returning anything, how to print out the result and if we can use a cursor to aggregate.

Comment: (1) `$unwind` is used with array fields. The `_id` in the collection `studentdetails` is _not_ an array - but, a sub-document (or an object); you don't need to unwind this field. (2) Also, you should be using the `$match` before the `$unwind: "$measures"` stage - this is more efficient.

Comment: Your `studentdetails` collection is not correctly formatted, please correct and post here